# Stored procedure returning result with no change

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have created a stored procedure for auto increment number it is returning same result, what I don't want. Then I change sequence of code now procedure working as I expected. I want to know the difference of below code snippet

This procedure is returning same result:

```
Create procedure AUTOINCNUM
as 
begin 
    set nocount on; 

    declare @Value int
    select @Value = CH_AUTOSERIES from tracker

    set @value = @value + 1
    return @value

    insert into tracker(CH_AUTOSERIES) values(@Value)
end
```

This procedure is working fine

```
Create procedure AUTOINCNUM
as 
begin 
    set nocount on; 

    declare @Value int
    select @Value = CH_AUTOSERIES from tracker
    set @value = @value + 1

    insert into tracker(CH_AUTOSERIES) values(@Value)
    return @value
end
```

Comment: The only difference I see is first procedure doesn't inserts anything into `tracker` table - this is because there is `return` statement prior to `insert`.

Comment: Also, do not try to roll your own auto-increment. It's bound to fail. Use sql-server's built in options, a sequence object for 2012+ versions, or a simple identity column for any version.

Answer (score 0):

1) use IDENTITY on column, where you want autoincrement.
2) first proc finished via return before new value is inserted into tracker table.
3) it is highly recommended to use transaction for that operations.

The IDENTITY column will solve most of these problems, see 1).

Comment: Hi Thanks for writing can you give me syntax for using identity in computed column im using like this   where i marked by * there i want to use auto increment please suggest                                                                             create table CareHospital(P_id as datepart(DAYOFYEAR,getdate())+*** +(datepart(year,getdate()))

Comment: Hi. I do not understand completely your problem. But you can see this example: `create table mytest(
id int identity not null,
tx varchar(10) not null,
p_id as datepart(dayofyear, getdate())+id+datepart(year, getdate()))
insert into mytest(tx) values('a')`